# angularjs function returned array is an object, not a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having some issues getting the function below to return as a usable string?

my code is this:

```
app.factory('Urls', ['$http', function($http) {
    var urls = {};
    urls.getUrls = function () {
        return  $http.get('json/dataUrls.json'); 
    }
    return urls
}]);

app.factory('Emails', ['$http', 'Urls', function($http, Urls) {

    var dataUrl = Urls.getUrls().then(function(response) {
        return response.data.emails;
    });
    console.log(dataUrl);

    var query = {};
    query.getItems = function() {
        return  $http.get('json/emails.json');  
    };
    return query;
}]);
```

below is the result of `console.log(dataUrl);` what i am trying to get is the value string...

```
f {$$state: {…}}
$$state
:
status
:
1
value
:
"json/emails.json"
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
```

Comment: could you please put your code in plunker/fiddler/codepen and make a runnable code snippet?

Comment: use `JSON.stringify(dataUrl)` to convert object to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataUrls you are getting from `var dataUrl = Urls.getUrls().then(...` is actually a Promise, not a String. I guess your intention is something like bellow:

```js
app.factory('Urls', ['$http', function($http) {
    var urls = {};
    urls.getUrls = function () {
        return  $http.get('json/dataUrls.json'); 
    }
    return urls
}]);

app.factory('Emails', ['$http', 'Urls', function($http, Urls) {

    var query = {};
    query.getItems = function() {
        return Urls.getUrls().then(function(response) {
            return response.data.emails;
        }).then(dataUrls => { // dataUrls here is a string, you can use it.
            return  $http.get(dataUrls); 
        });
    };
    return query;
}]);
```

Comment: Look at the code, you can pass the dataUrls because it's in the same scope.  `then(dataUrls => { return  $http.get(dataUrls + '/emails.json'); });`

Answer (score 2):

`Urls.getUrls().then(...)` returns a promise ([read more about this here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)), a datatype used to save a "reference" to a value which is fetched asynchronously.  Therefore, running `console.log` on `dataUrl` will return an object, not a string.

In order to get this value, you need to access it asynchronously.  The best way of doing this would be via [promise chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining):

```
app.factory('Urls', ['$http', function($http) {
    var urls = {};
    urls.getUrls = function () {
        return  $http.get('json/dataUrls.json'); 
    }
    return urls
}]);

app.factory('Emails', ['$http', 'Urls', function($http, Urls) {

    Urls.getUrls().then(function(response) {
        return response.data.emails;
    }).then(function(emails){
        console.log(emails);
    });

    var query = {};
    query.getItems = function() {
        return  $http.get('json/emails.json');  
    };
    return query;
}]);
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation and links. I have some reading to do to wrap my head around the concept i guess!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.factory('Urls', ['$http', function($http) {
    var urls = {};
    urls.getUrls = function () {
        return  $http.get('json/dataUrls.json'); 
    }
    return urls
}]);

app.factory('Emails', ['$http', 'Urls', function($http, Urls) {

    Urls.getUrls().then(function(response) {
        return response.data.emails;
    }).then(function(emails){
        console.log(emails);
    });

    var query = {};
    query.getItems = function() {
        return  $http.get('json/emails.json');  
    };
    return query;
}]);
```